# Multi-page table with caption aligned to the left edge

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, longtable, threeparttable

I am trying to achieve same thing as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358829/align-table-caption-with-left-hand-edge-of-tabular-material), but with *longtable* environment. Table itself is centered.

Using *caption* package and

```
\captionsetup[longtable]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
```

makes caption aligned to the left, but the caption sticks past the left edge of the table.

And I can't just add `margin=` or something, because my tables are not of the same width.

Is there a way to correct this, or maybe an alternative to *longtable*?

---

Example document:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=0pt,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3-4]

\begin{longtable}{l|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
%----------------------------------------
\caption{This label isn't where I want it}\label{tab:test}\\ \hline
Name & Description & Example\\
\endfirsthead
%----------------------------------------
\caption*{Table \ref{tab:test} (continued)}\\\hline
\endhead
%----------------------------------------
\hline
Something A & here's supposed to be some text & some text here \\ \hline
Something B & description of B & something more about B\\ \hline
Something C & describe C here & some example involving C \\ \hline
Something D & dfjashdfkjha sdflhasdkf hfsadf asdf & dsjkdlaskd ksjdla jdlkasj \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

Caption is aligned like this:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A small example would improve the question.

Comment: Perhaps `tabularx` with package `ltablex`? It brings the functionalities of `longtable` to tabularx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

you can determine caption start width by  setting `\LTcapwidth` to your table width. since its width is not know (in advance) it can be only by "trial and error" method ...

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=0pt,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-4]

{\setlength\LTcapwidth{0.85\linewidth}
\begin{longtable}{l|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
%----------------------------------------
\caption{This label isn't where I want it}\label{tab:test}\\ \hline
Name & Description & Example\\
\endfirsthead
%----------------------------------------
\caption*{Table \ref{tab:test} (continued)}\\\hline
\endhead
%----------------------------------------
\hline
Something A & here's supposed to be some text & some text here \\ \hline
Something B & description of B & something more about B\\ \hline
Something C & describe C here & some example involving C \\ \hline
Something D & dfjashdfkjha sdflhasdkf hfsadf asdf & dsjkdlaskd ksjdla jdlkasj \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

**rdit**:

in case, that you like use `ltablex` the width caption box width is the same as the width of table. therefore, it is known in advance and setting of table is simpler. for example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=0pt,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-4]

{\setlength\LTcapwidth{0.9\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{l|X|X}
%----------------------------------------
\caption{This label is where I want it}\label{tab:test}\\
    \hline
Name & Description & Example\\
\endfirsthead
%----------------------------------------
\caption*{Table \ref{tab:test} (continued)}\\\hline
\endhead
%----------------------------------------
\hline
Something A & here's supposed to be some text & some text here \\ \hline
Something B & description of B & something more about B\\ \hline
Something C & describe C here & some example involving C \\ \hline
Something D & dfjashdfkjha sdflhasdkf hfsadf asdf & dsjkdlaskd ksjdla jdlkasj \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: I guess this can be used in conjunction with `ltablex` (suggested by @Bernard) if I use the width given to `tabularx`.

Comment: yes, with it the situation is simpler since width of table is known in advance. similarly is when all columns are of `p{...}` type.

Comment: @Hedede, i add example of use `ltablex`.  now you can accept answer ... :-)